# Android ListView in a dialog - nullpointer exception

Tags: android

On a menu item click, I want to pop a dialog box.

```
private void getAcLookUpDialog() 
 {
try
     {
         Dialog dlg = new Dialog(this); 
         dlg.setContentView(R.layout.aclookup);
         dlg.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<b><H2>" + "Select A/C # " + "</H2></b>" ));   
         startManagingCursor(cur); 
         cur = actable.getAllAC();
         Log.d("Testing", "No of AC are " + cur.getCount());
         ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.aclookuplist);

         SimpleCursorAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.aclookup_listitem, cur, new String[] {"AC"}, new int[] {R.id.acactext});
         lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
         dlg.show();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         Log.d("Testing", "In getACLookUpdialog: error is: "+ e.toString());
     }

 }
```

It's throwing

12-13 08:58:43.968: DEBUG/Testing(3563): In getACLookUpdialog: error is: java.lang.NullPointerException

The query is getting data. I tried to put diff query which is working in my other app. 
aclookup.xml has a single listview.
aclookup_listitem has a single textview.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: after you have Logged your error message, do e.printStackTrace(); to get more detailed error information (e.g. what row you get the error from).

Comment: Ok. I am new to android. I added that. Now where should I see it. In Logcat, error tab ?

Comment: When displayed with `printStackTrace()` it'll show up as a large block of text under the warning category.

Comment: Thanks. It's erroring at lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

Comment: That's what I thought. I'll post an answer with solution and details :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First; when you have logged your errormessage with Log, call `e.printStackTrace()` to get all the details of the exceptions (e.g. on what line it occurred).

You get your error on

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

as `lv` is null.

I assume that the ListView exists in the dialog layout (R.layout.aclookup), so it is in the dialog you'll want to search for the ListView:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) dlg.findViewById(R.id.aclookuplist);
```